# Ubuntu Desktop shortcut icons not working

Tags: 18.04

I have following problem on my Ubuntu: Shortcut icons for some (not all) of the applications does not work. When right click and "Show Details" of such icon "Ubuntu Software" is been opened and appears: "No Application Found".
This is in both cases when I do it from Favorites icon, or from "Show Applications" icon.

For some of such applications I researched and found where is located their bin file. For example
IntelliJ IDEA: /snap/intellij-idea-community/current/bin/idea.sh
Viber: /opt/viber/Viber

For others like Notepadqq, Postman still not found.
I install applications using "Ubuntu Software".
So obviously only the shortcut information to the bin files is lost.

***Anyone to have idea how they could be recovered?***

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with Gnome 3.28.2, which runs on VMware® Workstation 14 Player version 14.1.1 build-7528167, which runs on Windows 10 Enterprise version 1809.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution to make shortcut icons to work again.
Simply install `snapd` if not installed:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Then disable and enable again applications with not responding shortcut icons:

```
sudo snap disable <appName>
sudo snap enable <appName>
```

For example:

```
sudo snap disable postman
sudo snap enable postman
```

Here some explanations that could be useful for some guys (that like me are not very in deep with Ubuntu) having other but similar problems:

I noticed all of not working icons are for applications that are located in `/snap` directory. (`snap` is an application that like `apt` or `apt-get` install packages on Ubuntu - see [comparison of them](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/a364ii/proscons_of_snap_vs_apt/)). I have never used `snapd` before but obviously `Ubuntu Software` application that I use for install\uninstall applications used it. So I needed to install first the `snapd` and then I just executed its commands `disable` and `enable` for the problematic application (Postman, Notepadqq and Opera browser in my case).

Answer (score 0):

In those cases I've encountered this problem, a change has happened. In the `.desktop` files, there are links to the icons.
You'll find the `.desktop` files in the folder `Desktop` (German: Schreibtisch).

For Opera, it could be `opera_opera.desktop`. There you'll find something like this:

```
Icon=/snap/opera/current/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/opera.png
```

Here, I've found, instead of the folder "current", a snap-number. This directory did no longer exist.
Simply change the link target for icon to "godzilla" or whatever you like...